# How can return the innerHTML inside my <a> tag?

Tags: javascript, html

```js
var checklist = document.getElementById("my-ul");
var items = checklist.querySelectorAll("a");

console.log(checklist);
console.log(items);

for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
  items[i].addEventListener("click", returnLetter);
}

function returnLetter() {
  alert(items.innerHTML);
}
```

```html
<ul id="my-ul" class="pager">
  <li><a href="#">A</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">B</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">C</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">D</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">E</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">F</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">G</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">H</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">I</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

My javascript seems to not return anything, the alert prints out 'undefined', but I can't figure out where my problem is. My goal is to return the letter corresponding to the button/link the user has clicked.

Comment: Use `this.innerHTML` instead of the `items.innerHTML`.

Answer (score 2):

Right now, your `returnLetter()` function is trying to print out the `innerHTML`s of *every `item`*. To fix this, only alert the `innerHTML` of that item by passing that item to the function, like so:

```
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    items[i].addEventListener("click", alertValue);
}
function alertValue() {
    alert(this.innerHTML);
});
```

The `this` in the event handler function will point to the element that is being clicked on (calling the event handler), instead of pointing to the `items` array.

See working example at [JSFiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/6u8txchv/).

Comment: His way of binding is better since he's not creating a new function in every iteration of the loop. Also his way makes it possible to use `.removeEventListener()`.

Comment: @squint Ok, I'll change it.

Comment: @squint Sorry again, careless mistake.

Answer (score 2):

It's returning `undefined` because `.querySelectorAll()` returns a [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) and `items` is a NodeList, which means that it doesn't have a `innerHTML` property. You need to access the property of an element in the NodeList.

You can pass the index of the clicked element:

[**Example Here**](https://jsfiddle.net/zg55hndq/)

```
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
  items[i].addEventListener("click", returnLetter.bind(items[i], i));
}

function returnLetter(i) {
  console.log(items[i].textContent);
}
```

However, a better option would be to use the [`this` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) to get a reference to the element the event occurred on. I'd also suggest using the `.textContent` property:

[**Example Here**](https://jsfiddle.net/r8g2qLde/)

```
function returnLetter() {
  console.log(this.textContent);
}
```

---

As a side note, you could also just attach a *single* event listener to the parent `ul` element, then access `event.target` to get a reference to the clicked `a` element:

[**Example Here**](https://jsfiddle.net/fj59aq42/)

```
checklist.addEventListener("click", returnLetter);

function returnLetter(e) {
  if (e.target.tagName === 'A') {
    alert(e.target.textContent);
  }
}
```

Comment: IMO, if the `.bind()` option is used, might as well bind `items[i]` instead of `this` (`window`).

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `this` on the event listener. For instance, your code could be rewritten as

```
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    items[i].addEventListener("click", clickCallback);
}

function clickCallback() {
    alert(this.innerHTML);
}
```

Comment: This method should be avoided as it creates one function in each iteration.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `this.innerHTML` as `this` points to the clicked element.

```js
var checklist = document.getElementById("my-ul");
var items = checklist.querySelectorAll("a");

console.log(checklist);
console.log(items);

for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
  items[i].addEventListener("click", returnLetter);
}

function returnLetter() {
  alert(this.innerHTML);
}
```

```html
<ul id="my-ul" class="pager">
  <li><a href="#">A</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">B</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">C</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">D</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">E</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">F</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">G</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">H</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">I</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```